# How can I transpile React Component (HOC/Inheritance Inversion) for npm package?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm

I`m making small npm package for react.
I want to make it overwrite some function of react component from other npm package.

It works when I import this component directory from my app.
But when It doesn't work when I use `npm link` on my app.

I tried to change export and tsconfg.json settings.
But those return same error.

Here is my component.

```js
import * as React from 'react'
import { Head } from 'something'

const MyHead = (
  WrappedComponent: typeof Head,
  injectString: string
): typeof Head => {
  return class extends WrappedComponent {
    someFunc() {}
  }
}

export default MyHead
```

Here is my app code.

```
import MyHead from "my-head"
import { Head } from 'something'

render() {
  const CustomHead = MyHead(Head, "Something")
  return (
    <CustomHead />
  )
}
```

Here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es3",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom", "es2016", "es2017"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "./dist"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "./src/**/*.tsx"
  ]
}
```

I got this error when only via `npm link`.
When I import directory this component from my app, I never get this error.

"TypeError: Class constructor Head cannot be invoked without 'new'"

Comment: I fixed. I changed target in tsconfig.json, tsc did transpile my component to class module and it works.